# Model.find() returns empty in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am working upon mongoose to list all the data from a collection in a db in mongodb:

from the requests:

```
http://localhost:3000/listdoc?model=Organization
```

i am doing the following code :

```
exports.listDoc = function(req, res) {    
var Model = mongoose.model(req.query.model); //This is defined and returns my desired model name
        Model.find().populate('name').exec(function(err, models) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {
                    status: 500
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(models);
            }
        });
};
```

I already have my entry in database
But the above code returns empty. Why?

EDIT : the following code also returns empty:

```
exports.listDoc = function(req, res) {
    var Model = mongoose.model(req.query.model);
    Model.find({},function(err,models){
        console.log(models);
         if (err) {
            res.render('error', {
                status: 500
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(models);
        }
    });
};
```

schema used :

```
var Organization = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues with your code snippet. Can you post your schema for Organization? Is your collection called "organizations" in mongodb?

Comment: i have added the schema used

Comment: Still looks OK. Are you connecting to the correct database name when you connect to mongodb?

Comment: How do you know you have an entry in the database? What's the collection's name?

Comment: collection name : organization and it have the documents, as i can see from mongo shell

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Your problem is mongoose pluralizes collections. Mongoose is querying "organizations" but your data is in mongodb as "organization". Make them match and you should be good to go. You can either rename it in mongodb via the mongo shell or tell mongoose about it. From the mongoose docs:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'actor' });

// or

schema.set('collection', 'actor');

// or

var collectionName = 'actor'
var M = mongoose.model('Actor', schema, collectionName)
```

Comment: What is the type of the 'data' in `model.find({}).exec(function(err,data){});` function? Is it an Array or something else?

Comment: It's an array of mongoose model instances.

Comment: I just spent entirely too long on this as well, I found the name mongoose.model('Link', linkSchema, 'links '); had a space at the end of it, which is not the same as it without the space.

Comment: I didn't really understand which part of this answer would fix my problem. After a while I realized, that the 3rd argument of mongoose.model() is a specified collection name. The first argument is the model's name, 2nd is the schema value, 3rd is the collection name. After I specified the 3rd value as my collection name, poof, the array was no longer empty

Answer (score 0):

From official [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified
>   paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

Try it without populate

```
Model.find({}).exec(function(err, models) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {
                    status: 500
                });
            } else {
                res.json(models);
            }
        });
```

Comment: this also returns empty..

Comment: try with `res.json(models)`

Comment: again this return empty