# PurchaseLogsModel.find() returns empty in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
  
  let Schema = mongoose.Schema

  let purchaseLogsSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String }, // user name
    email: { type: String },
    key: { type: String },
  })
  
  return mongoose.model('PurchaseLog', purchaseLogsSchema, 'purchaselog')
  
  
  /// then in my controller
   const data = await global.db.PurchaseLogsModel.find({ key: key }).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(500)
```

but data is empty array always i tried many solutions already :

Comment: Already asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628656/model-find-returns-empty-in-mongoose

Comment: i tried this solution but it doesn't work for me, still empty array returns :(

Comment: did you try `global.db.PurchaseLogsModel.find({ })`?

Comment: thank you, Tom your answer helps a lot, it was problem in schema creation :)